Stripe Apple Pay Confirmation Box does not show Confirm button
Confirmation box screenshot
I have integrated Google Pay and Apple Pay using @stripe/react-stripe-js. Google Pay works as expected but for Apple Pay when a user clicks the Apple Pay button, the dialog box/pop appears with no "Confirm Payment" button and so you're basically stuck there. There's no button to confirm the payment or proceed.
I have been searching through the internet but haven't found anything related to this. What am I doing wrong? Would really appreciate the help here.
Here's my component for Stripe form:
import {Elements, useElements, useStripe} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import StyledForm from '@/components/StyledForm/StyledForm';
import {PaymentElement} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import {PaymentRequestButtonElement} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import './paymentForm.scss';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { LoadingOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { STRIPE_PUBLISH_KEY, STRIPE_SECRET_KEY } from '@/common/config/config';


const stripePromise = loadStripe(STRIPE_PUBLISH_KEY as string);

const PaymentForm = (props: any) => {
      return (
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
            <CheckoutForm onSubmit={props?.onSubmit} />
        </Elements>
      )
    }
    
    const CheckoutForm = (props: any) => {
        const stripe: any = useStripe();
        const [paymentRequest, setPaymentRequest] = useState<any>(null);
      
        useEffect(() => {
          const price = localStorage.getItem('price') ?? 89;
          if (stripe) {
            const pr = stripe.paymentRequest({
              country: 'US',
              currency: 'usd',
              total: {
                label: 'LiProspect',
                amount: Number(price) * 100,
              },
              requestPayerName: true,
              requestPayerEmail: true,
            });
      
            // Check the availability of the Payment Request API.
            pr.canMakePayment().then((result: any) => {
                if (result) {
                  setPaymentRequest(pr);
                }
            });

            pr.on('paymentmethod', async (event: any) => {
              const result = await props?.onSubmit(false, event?.paymentMethod);
              if (!result) {
                event.complete('fail');
              } else {
                event.complete('success');
                console.log('paymentIntent success:', result);
              }
            });

            // pr.on('token', ( (event: any) => {
            //   console.log('token event', event);
            //   props?.onSubmit(false, event?.token)
            // }));
          }
          
          
        }, [stripe]);
      
        if (paymentRequest) {
          return (
            <>
              <PaymentRequestButtonElement options={{paymentRequest}}  />
            </>
          )
        }
      
        return <LoadingOutlined />;
      }

export default PaymentForm;


Strange, maybe it's specific to just your machine? do other people trying your site on their Macs have the same problem? There can also be other things potentially involved here, like if it's a laptop with TouchID and it has the lid closed while using an external monitor, or the buttons not appearing when screen recording.

Can confirm that we're facing this issue on every device (more than 2) we've checked so far. There is a loader and when it's done processing, the loader/button space goes blank as shown in the screenshot. Is there anything wrong with my implementation or am i missing anything?

Code seems fine, maybe share some example page so other people can try to replicate and/or ask Stripe support and provide a reproduction to them

Turns out it was a device specific issue and Apple Pay is working now. Thanks for your support!
